# Создание фрагмента из фрагмента

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, activity

В активити внизу использую *BottomNavigationView*. Она содержит две вкладки, каждая из которых содержит свой фрагмент. Эти два фрагмента содержат сверху *TabLayout*, для каждого фрагмента он разный. В *TabLayout* может быть несколько вкладок, и каждая вкладка содержит свой фрагмент с контентом.

**Вопрос.** Как это реализвать архитектурно. Создавать фрагменты *Tab* из фрагментов *BottomNavigationView*. Или сделать фрагменты *BottomNavigationView* активностями, находящимися внутри главной родительской активности. А то много где слышал что связанность фрагментов - зло, и запускать фрагмент из фрагмента не есть хорошо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Возможно не ответит на ваш вопрос, однако в Material Guide есть такое [предупреждение](https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html#usage):

> Caution.
>
> Combining bottom navigation and tabs may cause confusion, as their
>   relationship to the content may be unclear. Tabs share a common
>   subject, whereas bottom navigation destinations are top-level and
>   disconnected from each other.

[image: Пример того как не надо делать :)]

Если по делу, то рекомендации от Google для [Jetpack Navigation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing) - одна активити, а каждый вид контента отдельный фрагмент.